# jQuery, window.width() nativo e window.on resize na mesma condição

Tags: jquery, resize

Gostaria de saber se é possível uma maneira melhor do que esta, pois poupava a repetição de codigo:

normalmente faço:

```
if($(window).width() > 800) {

// BLAH BLAH BLAH

}

$(window).resize(function(){

    if($(window).width() > 800) {

        // BLAH BLAH BLAH

    }

});
```

Isto não me parece uma viável/boa implementação de código pois estou a repetir codigo (BLAH BLAH BLAH), haverá alguma maneira de pôr as duas condições dentro da mesma?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Crie uma função e execute a função nos dois casos...

```
function blah() {
    // BLAH BLAH BLAH
}

if($(window).width() > 800) {

    blah();

}

$(window).resize(function(){

    if($(window).width() > 800) {

        blah();

    }

});
```

ou eliminando completamente a repetição:

```
function blah() {
    if($(window).width() > 800) {
        // BLAH BLAH BLAH
    }
}

blah();

$(window).resize(function(){
    blah();
});
```

Obs.: Sempre declare a função antes dela ser chamada...

Comment: Mas eu tenho outras funções, dentro do BLAH BLAH BLAH

Comment: @Miguel não tem problema, execute tudo dentro da nova função normalmente...

Comment: Obgado, tinha pensado nisso mas pensei em 'php', que não dá para nested functions. Excelente

Comment: @Miguel Em php é possível até mesmo executar a própria função nela mesma...

Comment: Sim, mas não criar/declarar funções dentro de outras

Comment: Funciona sim, acabo de testar. Mas obviamente as funções declaradas dentro de outra função só estarão disponíveis depois que a função "mãe"  for chamada pelo menos uma vez... (É preciso verificar re declaração)

Comment: Obgado, tem razão, dentro de uma classe/objeto dá também?

Answer (score 2):

Você pode reduzir ainda mais o seu código.

```
$(window).on("resize", function(){
    if($(this).width() > 800) {

        // BLAH BLAH BLAH

    }
});
$(window).trigger('resize'); // Aqui você usa o 'trigger' para chamar o resize manualmente
```

Usando o trigger você consegue chamar o resize manualmente quando a tela carrega, fica bem mais limpo